# Spring Context not loaded

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext, servletcontextlistener

I am trying to migration an old project of mine from Spring 3.0.3.RELEASE to 4.0.9.RELEASE. I changed the pom.xml dependency to the 4.0.9, from that moment i am facing the problem. DispatcherServlet is not able to find the beans in the application context.

Following are my files

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>bootstrapConfig</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /com/core/choreographer/bootstrap/bootstrap-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.core.bootstrap.BootstrapManager
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.spring.http.SpringHttpContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>http-remoting</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:com/remote/springhttp-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>http-remoting</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/remoting/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The bootstrap-config.xml has all the beans to be inserted into the spring context. It is read by the **BootstrapManager** is child of **ServletContextListener** and inserted into the spring context. As follows.

```
public class BootstrapManager implements ServletContextListener
{
    public void contextInitialized( ServletContextEvent ctxEvt )
    {
        URL cfgURL = "location to the xml file" ;
        ServletContext context = ctxEvt.getServletContext() ;
        bootstrap.initialize( cfgURL ) ;
    }
}

public class Bootstrap
{
    public void initialize( final URL cfgURL ) throws BootstrapException
    {
        XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration() ;
        URL dtdURL = ReflectionUtil.getResource( Bootstrap.class, "bootstrap-config.dtd" ) ;

        // register it at the configuration
        config.registerEntityId( "-//Bootstrap//DTD 1.0//EN", dtdURL ) ;
        config.setValidating( true ) ;
        config.setURL( cfgURL ) ;
        config.load() ;
        initBootstrapElements( config ) ;
    }
    private void initBootstrapElements( final XMLConfiguration config ) throws BootstrapException
    {
        HierarchicalConfiguration cfg = null ;
        int numElements = config.getList( "bootstrap-element[@class]"     ).size() ;
        for( int i = 0 ; i < numElements ; i++ )
        {
            cfg = config.configurationAt( "bootstrap-element(" + i + ")" ) ;
            initElement( cfg ) ;
        }
    }
    public void initElement( final HierarchicalConfiguration config ) throws BootstrapException
    {
        String className = null ;
        String propName = null ;
        Object propVal = null ;
        HierarchicalConfiguration propCfg = null ;
        BootstrapElement element = null ;

        className = config.getString( "[@class]" ) ;
        element = (BootstrapElement) ReflectionUtil.createInstance( className.trim() ) ;

        beanWrapper.setWrappedInstance( element ) ;
        int numProps = config.getList( "property[@name]" ).size() ;
        for( int i = 0 ; i < numProps ; i++ )
        {
            propCfg = config.configurationAt( "property(" + i + ")" ) ;
            propName = propCfg.getString( "[@name]" ) ;
            propVal = propCfg.getProperty( "[@value]" ) ;
            if( propVal == null )
            {
                propVal = propCfg.getList( "value" ) ;
            }
            beanWrapper.setPropertyValue( propName, propVal ) ;
        }

        element.initialize() ;//This called the below new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    }
}

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( (String []) cfgLocations.toArray( new String [ 0 ] ) ) ;
```

Then I have a ContextLoaderListener

```
public class SpringHttpContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener {

    private ContextLoader loader;

    protected ContextLoader createContextLoader() {
        loader = new SpringHttpContextLoader();
        return loader;
    }

    public ContextLoader getContextLoader(){
        return loader;
    }

}
```

This is the ContextLoader

```
public class SpringHttpContextLoader extends ContextLoader {

    protected ApplicationContext loadParentContext(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws BeansException {
        SpringObjectFactory fact = BaseSpringObjectFactory.getInstance();
        return fact.getApplicationContext();
    }

}
```

This all worked perfectly while in Spring 3.0.3. As I tried to replace all the Jar to 4.0.9. the **Beans** defined in the springhttp-servlet.xml cannot find the beans defined in the bootstrap-config.xml.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. I am stuck from last 2-3 weeks in this.

Comment: why you have created a `BootstrapManager` for loading beans into spring context? use spring inbulid class [ContextLoaderListener](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html)

Comment: You should try to find in the logs (by incrementing `org.springframework` debug level) what application contextes are loaded by the framework. From the symptoms, I suppose Spring framework does not find the root context created by `BootstrapManager`, creates another one (empty) and uses it as root for the dispatcher servlet one.

Comment: @Rembo It is a legacy application I just got this project to convert.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I know the dispatcherServlet is not getting context created by BootstrapManager. how will I create a bridge of some kind? do you have any idea about that

Comment: Without knowing what does BoostrapManager and (what it does not), it is hard to guess. Does it correctly installs the newly created ApplicationContext as as ServletContext attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem it was with the `SpringHttpContextLoaderListener`. It was overridding a method `createContextLoader` and `getContextLoader` which was **deprecated** in **Spring version 3** so was removed in **Spring version 4**. Due to this the Custom Context was not loaded as the parent context.

```
public class SpringHttpContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener {

    private ContextLoader loader;

    protected ContextLoader createContextLoader() {
        loader = new SpringHttpContextLoader();
        return loader;
    }

    public ContextLoader getContextLoader(){
        return loader;
    }

}
```

**Solution**
Override `loadParentContext` of class `ContextLoader` in the class `SpringHttpContextLoaderListener`

```
protected ApplicationContext loadParentContext(ServletContext servletContext)
        throws BeansException {
    SpringObjectFactory fact = BaseSpringObjectFactory.getInstance();
    return fact.getApplicationContext();
}
```

This will set the custom created **Context** as the parent and will be available to all the **child context**

Answer (score 0):

If you are migrating to spring 4 most of these things need not to be performed. As the AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer loads both the context spring and application context.